# jQuery Moniter Text Input Live

Tags: jquery

I'm using this code to monitor an input field:

```
$('.qty-input').change(function(event) {
   var qty = $(this).val();
   var price = $(this).data('price');
   var prod = $(this).attr('name');
   var total = qty*price;
   $('#total'+prod).html(total);
});
```

But it only seems to function when I leave the input box.  How do I track the input in real time?

Comment: try other events, like keydown, keyup, keypress

Answer (score 1):

try other events, like this:

```
$('.qty-input').on( 'blur change click dblclick error focus focusin focusout hover keydown keypress keyup load mousedown mouseenter mouseleave mousemove mouseout mouseover mouseup resize scroll select submit', function(event){
    //alert(event.type);
    //your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `input` event  instead of the `change` event and don't forget to parse the strings to numeric.

```
$('.qty-input').on('input', function(event) {
   var qty = +$(this).val();
   var price = +$(this).data('price');
   var prod = $(this).attr('name');
   var total = qty*price;
   $('#total'+prod).html(total);
});
```

**NOTE**:

The input event event catches when the user **pastes** content into the input element.

```js
$('.qty-input').on('input', function(event) {
       var qty = +$(this).val();
       var price = +$(this).data('price');
       var prod = $(this).attr('name');
       var total = qty*price;
       $('#total'+prod).html(total);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
BREAD -- Qty: <input type="text" name="bread" data-price="2" class="qty-input" />

Total: <span id="totalbread"></span><br>

MILK -- Qty: <input type="text" name="milk" data-price="12.35" class="qty-input"/>

Total: <span id="totalmilk"></span><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/175s3st5/

using the following code:

```
<input type="text" id="myText" />

<div id="output" style="border: 1px solid black"></div>

    var textBox = $("#myText");
    var output = $("#output");

    $(textBox).on('keyup', function(){
    $(output).html($(this).val());
    })
```

This is an example of the "keyup" event, there are a lot of other events you can use.

Here is some documentation for:

keyboard events: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/

mouse events: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Have a look through others and play around with the examples.